# Javascript issue on SAFAR, Chrome & Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

the onclick button is unable to submit the request in my jsp page. Please refer the below code. It works in IE but does not works in SAFARI browser, Chrome and firefox. The Submit button just disables and the screen stops there.

This is my submit function

```
function submitTicket(actionType) {
    var result = validateForm();
    if (result == true) {
        if (submitcount == 0 && actionType == "createTicket") {
            submitcount++;
            document.forms[0].pageAction.value = 'submit';
            document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled=true;             
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and it is called from here

```
<input type="submit"
       value='${submitBut}'
       id="submitBtn"
       onclick="javascript:return submitTicket('createTicket');" />
```

Comment: it is called from here &ensp;<input type="submit"  value='${submitBut}' id="submitBtn"  onclick="javascript:return submitTicket('createTicket');" />&ensp;

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Did you try at least to debug it? Check difference between IE and any other browser. For example, what does return `validateForm()`? What is this method? You need to provide more context regarding your issue

Comment: I tried debugging the Submit function. It goes well and stops at the line &ensp;<input type="submit" value='${submitBut}' id="submitBtn" onclick="javascript:return submitTicket('createTicket');" />&ensp